# GCP Stackdriver Logs-Based Metrics for custom payload value

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Already created my filters with a specific value from the jsonPayload.

[image: GCP StackDriver]

I want to create a metric which plots the values of Process_time.

Can anyone please help, how to create such metrics?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "CREATE METRIC" button above the filter box and use `jsonPayload.process_time` as the **Field name**

The other attributes are generally described in the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics